# cursor will not move to second screen

Tags: windows-7

I have install Synergy correctly on the server machine.  Then installed correctly on the Client machine.  All seems as it is explained in the installation instructions, but I can not find where to configure the "Screen List" to indicate right, left, middle, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring the below steps and please check the outcome.

Select the "Share this computer's keyboard and mouse (server)" radio button

Click the "Screens & Links Configure" button

Click the "+ button" to add the server to the Screens list

Enter the name of server (the computer's name is the recommended name)

Optionally enter other names the server is known by. Click OK

Use the "+ button" to add your other computers

Using a computer's name as its screen name is recommended. Choose desired screen options on the Add Screen dialog

Use the controls under Links to link screens together then Click (once) on the server's name in the Screens list

Choose the screen to the left of the server; use --- if there is no screen to the left of the server
Choose the screens to the right, above and below the server

Repeat the above steps for all the other screens

Click OK to close the Screens & Links dialog

Use Options... to set desired options

If the server's screen name is not the server's computer name: Click Advanced...
Enter the server's screen name next to Screen Name and Click OK. Now perform a test.

Hope this helps.